# MS Access Set Parent Form Property from Child Property

Tags: vba, ms-access, vbscript

How does one go about setting access form parent form property(property within the parent form) from the child form property?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To refer to the parent in code from the child form code page:

```
Me.Parent.MyControl
```

Or

```
Forms!MainForm.MyControl
```

Comment: +1 The "Me" keyword is not mandatory but helps for reference when your reading the code back